# Retrieve property value from include'd / import'ed project

Tags: ant

I am trying to use ant's include or import tasks to use a common build file. I am stuck at retrieving properties from included file.

These are my non-working samples, trying to retrieve "child-property"

## Using ant import

### parent file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="parent" basedir=".">
    <import file="child.xml" />
    <target name="parent-target">
        <antcall target="child-target" />
        <echo message="(From Parent) ${child-property}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

### child file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="child" basedir=".">
    <target name="child-target">
        <property name="child-property" value="i am child value" />
        <echo message="(From Child) ${child-property}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

### *output*

```
parent-target:

child-target:
     [echo] (From Child) i am child value
     [echo] (From Parent) ${child-property}
```

## Using ant include

### parent file

```
<project name="parent" basedir=".">
    <include file="child.xml" />
    <target name="parent-target">
        <antcall target="child.child-target" />
        <echo message="(From Parent) ${child-property}" />
        <echo message="(From Parent2) ${child.child-property}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

### child file

*same as above*

### *output*

```
parent-target:

child.child-target:
     [echo] (From Child) i am child value
     [echo] (From Parent) ${child-property}
     [echo] (From Parent2) ${child.child-property}
```

How can I access "child-property" from parent?

Answer (score 4):

When you use the [`antcall`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task a new Ant cycle is started for the antcall'ed task - but that doesn't affect the context of the caller:

> The called target(s) are run in a new
>   project; be aware that this means
>   properties, references, etc. set by
>   called targets will not persist back
>   to the calling project.

One way to make your simple example to work would be to change the first parent to:

```
<target name="parent-target" depends="child-target">
    <echo message="(From Parent) ${child-property}" />
</target>
```

Then the child-target will be executed in the parent context before the parent-target.

But, you may find that there are side affects to running the child task in the context of the parent that you don't want.

Comment: "depends" somewhat works. but the problem with it is not being able to pass parameters to the task. I tried to define a global property in the parent, which can be retrieved in the child, but it limits the ability to pass different parameters for multiple calls. I will try "variable" tasks in ant-contrib in order to exchange variables. thx btw.

Comment: @b10y - Another option that comes to mind is to continue to use antcall but, in the child, write the properties you want to propagate back to the parent to a file using 'echo file='.  Then, in the parent, read the 'saved' properties from that file using 'property file='.

Answer (score 1):

It is a different approach but you may use *macrodef*.

**parent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="parent" basedir=".">
<import file="child.xml"/>
<target name="parent-target">
    <child-macro myid="test"/>
    <echo message="(From Parent) ${child-property}" />
</target>
```

**child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="child" basedir=".">
<macrodef name="child-macro">
    <attribute name="myid" default=""/>
    <sequential>
        <property name="child-property" value="i am child value" />
        <echo message="(From Child) ${child-property}" />
        <echo message="Received params: myId=@{myid}"/>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
</project>
```

**output**

```
parent-target:
 [echo] (From Child) i am child value
 [echo] Received params: myId=test
 [echo] (From Parent) i am child value
```

Answer (score 1):

Ant-contrib's [runtarget](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/runtarget.html) task has sufficiently solved my problem. It mignt not be suitable for others since it runs the target in parent's context. Guess there is no "one solution for all" for these kind of problems until Ant officially supports variables.

### Parent

```
<project name="parent" basedir=".">
    <!-- insert necessary antcontrib taskdef here-->
    <include file="child.xml" />
    <target name="parent-target">
        <var name="x" value="x"/>
        <runtarget target="child.child-target"/>
        <echo message="From Parent: ${x}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Child

```
<project name="child" basedir=".">
    <property name="pre" value="childpre" />
    <target name="child-target">
        <var name="x" value="${x}y" />
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
parent-target:

child.child-target:
     [echo] From Parent: xy
```